# How to Smooth Movement on Camera in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to do when a object moves camera will smooth that move. I can only explain this with images.
[image: Problem]

Is this possible and what is name of this effect. And is this possible for 3D objects (or only 2D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect that you're looking for most likely is `Motion Blur`. You'll have to look into `Post-Processing` for that.

Here's a resource:
https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/post-processing-effects-motion-blur-2019-3